# Making asyncio.gather raise an exception immediately

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm running some time consuming computations in separate tasks with `asyncio`. Sometimes they fail and raise an exception. If one of them fails I would like for `asyncio.gather` to propagate that exception immediately, rather than waiting for all tasks to finish first. A minimal runnable mock-up to illustrate:

```
import asyncio
import time


async def main():
    num_reps = 10
    counter = 0

    async def generate():
        nonlocal counter
        # The sleep simulates doing some serious computing. The use of time.sleep
        # rather than asyncio.sleep is intentional: Doing the computing blocks the CPU.
        time.sleep(1)
        counter += 1
        print(counter, end="\r")  # This helps us see the calculation proceed.
        raise RuntimeError  # This simulates the computation going wrong.

    tasks = [generate() for _ in range(num_reps)]
    result = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return result


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

What happens here is that this runs for ~10 seconds and the printed `counter` ticks all the way up to 10 before the `RuntimeError` is raised. What I would like to happen is for the `RuntimeError` to be raised immediately after the first task raises it.

My understanding, correct me if I'm wrong, is that the question here is this: Once the first task hits the `raise RuntimeError`, which task gets the interpreter lock next? It seems that the lock goes to the next `generate` task, and the next one, and the next one, and only once they are all done/crashed does it go back to `asyncio.gather`, which then wakes up to the fact that its tasks are raising errors and propagates them. I would rather like for the lock to go to `asyncio.gather` immediately when the first task raises the `RuntimeError`, enough so that it can realise that there's an exception for it to propagate.

I'm aware of the `return_exceptions` argument of `asyncio.gather`, that's not the solution here. I'm also aware that the above doesn't achieve actually parallelising the computation, the use of coroutines makes sense for other reasons not evident from the mock-up.

I think `TaskGroups` from Python 3.11 might solve this, but unfortunately I'm confined to 3.9.

Comment: The answer by @jsbueno and the conversation in its comments helps me understand a lot why this behaves the way it does. I'm still looking for a way to change that behavior, but I think it's going to require more than a small tweak to how I use `asyncio.gather` or `asyncio.wait`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`asyncio.wait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait) instead of `gather` then, as it provides more fine control, and includes the option to return on the first exception.

However the `FIRST_EXCEPTION` return_when for wait won't work for expected: the asyncio loop will still run a full round of steps in the active tasks (and if they don't have enough `await` pauses, they will simply run to completion, even if a sibling task raised).

But the `FIRST_COMPLETED` variant, along with activelly calling wait for the remaining tasks in case no exception is raised, works:

```
import asyncio
import time


async def main():
    num_reps = 10
    counter = 0

    async def generate():
        nonlocal counter
        # The sleep simulates doing some serious computing. The use of time.sleep
        # rather than asyncio.sleep is intentional: Doing the computing blocks the CPU.
        time.sleep(1)
        # add an await anyway, because otherwise asyncio behaves badly:
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
        counter += 1
        print(counter)  # This helps us see the calculation proceed.
        raise RuntimeError()  # This simulates the computation going wrong.

    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(generate()) for _ in range(num_reps)]
    results = []
    while tasks:
        done_tasks, pending = await asyncio.wait(tasks, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
        for task in done_tasks:
             if exc:=task.exception():
                 print(f"exception raised: {exc}, aborting")
                 return results
             results.append(task.result())
        tasks = pending
    return results


# this is the old way:
# asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())

# On newer Python versions do this:
asyncio.run(main())
```

Although, this will not work if the CPU intensive code do not yield often to the asyncio loop. No can do.

If in your real code you can spread some asyncio.sleep(0)s  so that tasks have a chance to interruptible, it might work (see bellow, with 10 0.1 second synchronous sleeps instead of a single one).

Otherwise, just run your CPU intensive code in another thread with `run_in_executor` - async can't help you alone.

```
import asyncio
import time

async def watcher(tasks):
    while True:
        for t in tasks:
            if t.done() and t.exception():
                for t1 in tasks:
                    if not t.done():
                        t.cancel()
                        return
        await asyncio.sleep(0)



async def main():
    num_reps = 10
    counter = 0

    async def generate(n):
        nonlocal counter
        # The sleep simulates doing some serious computing. The use of time.sleep
        # rather than asyncio.sleep is intentional: Doing the computing blocks the CPU.
        for i in range(10):
            await asyncio.sleep(0)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            if n == 1:
                raise RuntimeError()
        counter += 1
        print(counter, end="\r")  # This helps us see the calculation proceed.
        #raise RuntimeError  # This simulates the computation going wrong.

    tasks = []
    tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(watcher(tasks)))
    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(generate(i)) for i in range(num_reps)]
    result = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return result


asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: This sounds very promising, but in practice it seems to suffer from the same issue. Even though `return_when=asyncio.FIRST_EXCEPTION` is used, it runs through all the tasks before returning. I've submitted an edit to fix a few bugs and make this runnable so you can try it yourself.

Comment: well, your tasks are not proper async - if you use `await asyncio.sleep(1)` instead of `time.sleep(1)` you should get a different result. If your tasks are computational intensive instead of I/O bound, you won't get benefits of using pure asyncio as well - depending on the task you can use a `run_in_executor` call - even using a ProcessPoolExecutor - so that you can take advantage of parallelism.

Comment: As I said in the OP, I am aware of this. In my real use case sometimes the task is computationally bound, sometimes I/O, and I want it to parallelise nicely in the second case and run synchronously but smoothly in the first. More to the point, this still doesn't help me understand why `return_when=asyncio.FIRST_EXCEPTION` doesn't actually return when it encounters its first exception.

Comment: probably because of how the asyncio loop calls co-routines - the first call up to the point where there is an await is made asynchronously inside the loop.

Insert an `await asyncio.sleep(0)` in the first time in the co-routine - if I am correct, the behavior should change.

Comment: well, I tried it myself, and it indeed did not work. I am back on it, but it is trickier than I thought.

Comment: There it is. Activelly watching for results with `FIRST_COMPLETED` instead of `FIRST_EXCEPTION` in `asyncio.wait` does the trick

Comment: I really appreciate your effort in trying to help me here. Unfortunately, even with the `FIRST_COMPLETED` trick you implement above, the behavior still remains the same for me: The script in total takes ~10s to finish, rather than ~1s. Using the `await asyncio.sleep(0)` affects a bit when the prints pop up, but all 10 tasks still run to finish before main gets to process the exception(s).

Comment: On browsing some CPython Github issues, this seems to be known and perhaps even intended behavior of `asyncio.wait` and the `FIRST_COMPLETED` and `FIRST_EXCEPTION` options. There's a CPython PR [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/83852) trying to clarify the documentation.

Comment: yep - I've made further tests - the async tests really leave no chance to be cancelled without yielding to the loop - and yielding before the first sleep will run before the RuntimeError. After, and it just gets a chance after all the sleeps have gone through.

I've updated the answer to reflect that.